# uwsgi+nginx how to change group?

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

im trying uwsgi+nginx+django tutorial, and got stuck there (link links directly to section where i got stuck)
https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#if-that-doesn-t-work

nginx error.log says:

```
2015/03/09 13:44:51 [crit] 11642#0: *16 connect() to unix:///home/gaucan/temp/my_app/mysite.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///home/gaucan/temp/my_app/mysite.sock:", host: "localhost:8000"
```

and tutorial says to fix it,  do the following: 

`You may also have to add your user to nginx’s group (which is probably www-data), or vice-versa, so that nginx can read and write to your socket properly.`

But im linux noob and i don't know how to this, or how to find out if that group is www-data or not... already did some mess before with changing owner to some folders to user:"gaucan"

also i did skip in tutorial this step:

`You will need the uwsgi_params file, which is available in the nginx directory of the uWSGI distribution, or from https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/conf/uwsgi_params`

since i don't know which directory is `nginx directory of the uWSGI distribution`...

btw i use FEDORA if thats any help...

Comment: Can you add the output of

ls -al /home/gaucan/temp/my_app/mysite.sock

Comment: srw-rw-r--. 1 gaucan gaucan 0 Mar  9 14:18 /home/gaucan/temp/my_app/mysite.sock

Answer (score 2):

To find the permissions of a file:

```
ls -al unix:///home/gaucan/temp/my_app/mysite.sock
```

That will print some columns of information, the first of which will be the unix permissions:

```
-rw-rw-r--   1 user group  1234 Mar 9 2015  name of file
```

The first dash is special, just ignore it.  The next three characters represent the read, write, and exeute permissions of the User who owns the file.  Next 3 represent the group who owns the file.  The last 3 represent everyone else.

The nginx process needs to be able to write to that socket file.

You don't have to add your user to the same group as nginx, but you do need to allow proper permissions on the socket.  Those instructions as written don't make 100% sense to me.

-- **instructions to add your user to a group anyway** --

To find the user of a process:

```
ps aux | grep nginx
```

One of the output columns will be the user of the nginx process

To find out what groups you belong to:

```
groups
```

That will print a space separated list of unix groups that you belong to.

To set a brand new list of groups that you belong to

```
sudo usermod -G group1,group2  username
```

Note that the groups are comma separated and they will wipe out any existing groups, so you need to re-type all the existing groups into that command with commas.

Alternatively, use the --append flag of usermod:

```
sudo usermod --append -G www-data username
```

You must completely logout and login again to gain the effect of the new groups.  (There may exist a shortcut to reload your groups, but I'm not aware of one)

Comment: btw is there any better tutorial? i only found this old ones which are for i guess old nginx? since they say to use i.e. `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart`
, but in new u can only do `nginx -s reload` which is i guess the equivalent of what they meant... etc... and also i think the new nginx creates user called `nginx` not `www-data` , since `www-data` didnt even exist when i tried `groups www-data`

Comment: so, the easiest and LEAST secure way is to allow everyone to write to your socket.

chmod 777 /home/gaucan/temp/my_app/mysite.sock

Comment: Your /run/nginx.pid error.  That sounds like a brand new problem.  Did you try to change the user that nginx is running under?
What is the output of ls -al /run/nginx.pid ?

Comment: @chudagie i already did that , but still no help, i guess i didnt do it correctly... i even added nginx and gaucan to root group and still same error

Comment: @chudagie i deleted that new error now, since it was only caused by that i was starting nginx as root , and it was somehow bugged and i could quit that since i was logged of root

Comment: im still back at our old error that mysite.sock is permission denied.... and always when i go to localhost:8000 it says `502 Bad Gateway`

Comment: in ubuntu 16.06: sudo usermod --append -G group1 username

Answer (score 1):

I solved the "Permission denied" problem by changing the socket location to "/tmp/sock.sock". My socket was previously somewhere under /root and I kept getting "Permission denied" even after I did "chmod 777".

Answer (score 0):

not sure what everything wrong i did, but simply after spending whole day on it, i retried the tutorial, but i tried to write directly all config into `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`  and it did work then... so that was the bad steps at the tutorial (creating own mysite_nginx.conf and then symlinking with some sites-enabled  which didnt even exist in this new version of nginx... )

also did placed socket in `/tmp/sock.sock` mb that helped too..